# How to save a survey in multiple languages in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There are similar questions on this topic but I did not find the appropriate answer.

I need to save a survey that contains metadata about the survey, questions and answers.
This survey is defined in a backoffice app (next.js) and the survey itself is shown to a user in a mobile app.

There are 2 kinds of answers: multiple answers (I have to manually define the answers in multiple languages and then the user will vote for one of them) or an open answer (the user will write its own answer).

Each question and answer also has metadata and the questions and answers (in case of multiple answers) themselves should be saved in several languages.

The survey results are kept in a separate collection with the user info, question and answer.
What is the best way to manage this?

Should I keep everything in the same document like this:

```
const SurveysDalSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    metadata1: String,
    metadata2: String,
    questions: [
      {
        image_url: String,
        event_type: String,
        timing_in_hours: Number,
        stage: String,
        answer_type: String, // multiple or single
        questions: [{
          language: { type: String, unique: true },
          text: String,
        }],
        answers: [{
          icon_url: String,
          text: [{
            language: { type: String, unique: true },
            text: String
          }]
        }],
      },
    ]
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);
```

or should I manage the answers in another collection with a reference to the question?
the first one is more obvious but the validations are complex.

Comment: Yes, you should manage *answers* in another collection. Same applies for *questions*.

Comment: thanks! can you explain your considerations for that?

Comment: I would also split it up. You basically have questions, answers and meta data. You can relate questions and answers via an intermediate table. To assign meta data to a question answer pair, you can do a similar thing and store a meta-data id into the intermediate table. The meta-data is kept separate.

Comment: @NathanBarel You should read more about *denormalization* and *normalization* regarding DBs. Regarding NoSQL and MongoDB : https://dev.to/damcosset/mongodb-normalization-vs-denormalization There are many stackoverflow questions also regarding this topic. Even on MongoDB: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/schema-design-many-to-many-relationships-and-normalization/209349